# How to create a testPlan in jmeter in non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

I want to create a Test Plan in jmeter from command line. How to create a .jmx file from command line?

I have created one using the following command:

```
copy NUL testPlan.jmx
```

The file created successfully. But when I Type the following command shown below, it requests me to supply a script with .jmx extension:

```
D:\Adit\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin>jmeter-n -t testPlan.jmx -l log.jtl
Please supply a script name with the extension .jmx
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have searched the net and all I found is how to run the testPlan from command line using jmeter. But I want to create the testPlan from command line first. Is it possible?

My Java version is "1.8.0_77" and Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03).

Answer (score 4):

What do you expect of empty Test Plan? JMeter's .jmx files are basically XML files which define Load Test flow. If you're comfortable with XML generation over command line you can inspect an existing test and try to replicate it.

Other options are:

- You can use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) to generate a JMeter test plan from Java code:

  - [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
  - [Demo Project](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/)
- You can use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper to JMeter. You should be able to create a test using command-line parameters.

Comment: For the lazy: look at `printable_docs/demos/` and `bin/templates`.